# Logging into Flask Web App from a Python script

Tags: python, flask

Is it possible to login into a Flask Website (that utilizes `flask_user`) from a Python script in order to make restful calls marked with `@login_required`?

requirements:
 The script needs to be distributed (so its use cannot be limited to one account) and I have access to the Flask backend (in order to make modifications if need be).

Thanks, JJ

Comment: So, to clarify, you need to log in to a website to make calls to a REST API?

Comment: It utilizes some code that obfuscates the login-aspects of the program. (I believe it might be a bit more complicated than sending a json, though I can't find any documentation on it)